# Bootstrap not rendering item properly on page

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I am using bootstrap to design my page.

```
const AddRestaurent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="mb-4">
            <form action="">
                <div className="form-row">
                   <div className="col">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="location"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <select className="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2">
                            <option disabled>Price Range</option>
                            <option value="1">$</option>
                            <option value="2">$$</option>
                            <option value="3">$$$</option>
                            <option value="4">$$$$</option>
                            <option value="5">$$$$$</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>               
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddRestaurent
```

These components should come on same row. but they are coming in different row. what mistake I am doing. I have included library in my index.html

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"form-group row"` and not `"form-row"`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using bootstrap 5.0.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/

Try using `row` instead of `form-row`.

You can also use gutter (ex. `g-2`) to adjust gutter width.

```
const AddRestaurent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="mb-4">
            <form action="">
                <div className="row">
                   <div className="col">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="location"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <select className="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2">
                            <option disabled>Price Range</option>
                            <option value="1">$</option>
                            <option value="2">$$</option>
                            <option value="3">$$$</option>
                            <option value="4">$$$$</option>
                            <option value="5">$$$$$</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>               
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddRestaurent
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use row as classname instead of group-row

```
<div className="form-row"> replace with <div className="row">
```